# Create vertical space (gaps) between rows in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there any way to have my vertically stacked buttons have a gap between them, other than using the break (`<br>`) tag?

I've exhausted every other option and nothing seems to work other than using the break (`<br>`) tag in the html sheet after each div.

Here is my code (**break tags taken out**):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lat;
  var long;
  $.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data2) {
    lat = data2.latitude;
    long = data2.longitude;
    console.log(lat);
    console.log(long);
    //creating an api with the user's geolocation 
    var api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&appid=b6e4d569d1718b07a44702443dd0ed77"


    //json call for the api
    $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
      var fTemp;
      var cTemp;
      var tempSwap = true;

      var weatherType = data.weather[0].description;
      var kTemp = data.main.temp;
      var windSpeed = data.wind.speed;
      var city = data.name;
      $("#city").html(city);
      fTemp = (kTemp * (9 / 5) - 459.67).toFixed(2);
      cTemp = (kTemp - 273).toFixed(1);

      $("#api").html(api);
      $("#weatherType").html(weatherType);

      $("#fTemp").html(fTemp + "&#8457;");
      $("#fTemp").click(function() {
        if (tempSwap === false) {
          $("#fTemp").html(fTemp + "&#8457;");
          tempSwap = true;
        } else {
          $("#fTemp").html(cTemp + "&#8451;");
          tempSwap = false;
        }
      });


      $("#windSpeed").html(windSpeed + "m/sec");
    })

    if (fTemp >= 100) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/6ss6kyuhl/yamaha_yzf_r1-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg)");
    } else if (fTemp < 90) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/lapdsz8y1/beyonce_knowles_2-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg)")
    } else if (fTemp > 80) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/i54s2ennd/Beyonce_in_Jamaica.jpg)")
    } else if (fTemp < 70) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/t4pzebr0p/golf_course_landscape-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg)")
    } else if (fTemp < 60) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url()")
    } else if (fTemp < 50) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/8xcjlpoax/rihanna_9-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg)")
    } else if (fTemp = 37.40) {
      $("container").css("background-image", url("https://s2.postimg.org/8xcjlpoax/rihanna_9-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg"))
    } else if (fTemp < 30) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/nhtmgb6c9/white_snowy_road-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg)")
    } else if (fTemp < 20) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/9a3xrntnd/rihanna_dior_sunglasses-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg)")
    } else if (fTemp < 10) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url()")
    } else if (fTemp < 0) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/r05mdaf49/snowy_cabin_mountains_winter-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg)")
    } else if (fTemp < -10) {
      $("container").css("background-image", "url(https://s2.postimg.org/7v2d3i5l5/skiing-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg)")

    };


  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://s1.postimg.org/14i3xf2um7/Hummer-_H1-_Snow-_Turn-_Headlights-1024x768.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.About {
  /*background-color: blue;*/
  /*transform: translateY(650%)*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em
}

.holder {
  border: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .80);
  width: 55%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#city,
#weatherType,
#fTemp,
#windSpeed {
  transform: translateY(9%);
  background-color: #c6c6c4;
  border-bottom: 2px inset #FFF;
  border-right: 2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  /*padding-bottom: 2px ;*/
}

.btn.btn-default {
  color: #0040ff;
  font-size: .80em;
  font-family: Orbitron, sans-serif;
  line-height: 2.45em;
}

@media(min-width: 500px) {
  .holder {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<title></title>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="About">
      <h2>Your Local Weather App</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="btn btn-default" id="city">
      </div>
      <div class="btn btn-default" id="weatherType">
      </div>
      <div class="btn btn-default" id="fTemp">
      </div>
      <div class="btn btn-default" id="windSpeed">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/NwNOgq/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you already have for wider screens:

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .holder {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;  
  }
}
```

Add this for smaller screens, where you want your elements vertically stacked in one column:

```css
.holder {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;  
   grid-row-gap: 1em;
}
```

[**Revised CodePen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYRBYW?editors=1100)

Grid provides `grid-column-gap`, `grid-row-gap` and `grid-gap` (the shorthand), which create space between grid items (but not between items and the container).

> [**10.1. Gutters: the `grid-column-gap`, `grid-row-gap`, and
>   `grid-gap`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#gutters)
>
> These properties specify the gutters between grid rows and grid
>   columns, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! OMG! ....I must admit though, that I'm a bit confused about this wording: 
**"This is what you already have for wider screens:"** 
`@media(min-width: 500px){
  .holder{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;  
  }
}
`
**"Add this for smaller screens:"** smaller screens? Why wouldn't that go under the `@media (min-width: 500px){}` CSS rule?.....since it styles the buttons to be vertical for `500px` and less....(which is in essence for smaller screens...?

`.holder {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;  
   grid-row-gap: 1em;
}
`

Comment: `min-width: 500px` means screens of 500px or *more* (i.e. a minimum of 500px).

Comment: `max-width: 500px` means screens of 500px or *less*  (i.e. a maximum of 500px).

Comment: @Michael_B......I hate being confused by that! Thanks for your time! So up to a minimum of `500px`, my buttons will be in columns, but at `499px` and below it will automatically stack. And then for `max-width` at above `500px`(`501px` and up) it will stack and  below `500px` (`499px` and below) it will be columns...??? Correct?

Answer (score 0):

To define row and column gap independently:

```
grid-row-gap: 32px;
grid-column-gap: 16px;
```